# Ambiguious constructors with single argument: initializer_list and int

Tags: c++, c++11

What determines which constructor should be used when initializing objects using this syntax; is it compiler dependent? (Using VS2015):

```
Vector v { 3 };
```

I'm creating my own `Vector` class (learning C++11) and I have the following:

```
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(initializer_list<double> lst);
    Vector(int s);
    // ...
private:
    double* elem;
    int sz;
};
```

and:

```
int main()
{
    Vector v1 { 3 };  //calls init_list ctor
    Vector v2 { static_cast<int>(3)}; //calls init_list ctor
    Vector v3 = 3;    //call int ctor
}
```

My initial thought was using the `{ 3 }` syntax would call the constructor that accepts an `int`, then realized that it makes sense since I could also use something like `{ 3, 4, 5, 6 }` and that would work--the array passed would been seen as doubles and a `Vector` would be instantiated.

Then I thought, "how can I use the `{}-notation` and call the constructor that accepts an `int`? " I tried casting it to an `int` so that it would force use of said constructor but that didn't happen.  That's when I found out I can use the method used to init `v3`.

I played around a little bit more and removed the constructor with the `initializer_list<double>` argument, and to my surprise, initializing `v1` and `v2` was calling the constructor that takes an `int` for an argument.

So, is this normal/standard?  Is it considered a feature? I would think the `int` constructor would have precedence when passing a single `int` to the initializer vs. an implicit cast to `double` and `double*`.

Comment: http://probablydance.com/2013/02/02/the-problems-with-uniform-initialization/

Comment: The short answer is that if it can possibly be interpreted as an initializer_list, it will. Only if that fails completely will other possibilities be considered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is standard. If there is a `std::initializer_list` constructor with compatible arguments, that will be chosen over a different constructor if list-initialization is used.

```
Vector v3 = 3;
```

That is valid because you have a non-explicit constructor taking an `int`, so implicit conversions from `int` to `Vector` are allowed. That's generally not such a good idea as you can get implicit conversions when you don't want them.

The way to call a non-initializer-list constructor when an initializer-list constructor exists is to use parentheses for the initialization:

```
Vector v1 (3); //int constructor
Vector v2 {3}; //initializer_list constructor
```

Generally its best to avoid these logically ambiguous constructors if you can help it, as these rules can be annoying. In this case, since you are emulating `std::vector`, its probably okay.